# where cluase not working after security rule in google cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

this is my security rule for firebase, it throwing permission for query :

```
app.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==' ,'test@gmail.com').get().then(snap => console.log(snap.docs[0].data())).catch(err => console.log("err",err));
```

the above query is throwing permission error!!

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rule is saying that a user can only read the document in users with an id that's the same as their authenticated UID.  But your query is trying to read any document where the email field has some value.  Since that query could possibly try to read documents other than the one that matches the UID, the query will fail every time.  With the rules you have now, the client is only allowed to get() their own specific document, with no other queries allowed.

Comment: how do i make this query run /

Comment: You will have to remove the read permission that forces the client to only read documents with a specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that security rules **are not filters**.

Example:

my uid: 123123

**doc1**:
   email: test@gmail.com, id: 123123

The securtiy rule will pass for doc1.

**doc2**: email: test@gmail.com, id: 321321

The security rule will fail for doc2.

That is because your security rule is saying that if **ALL** documents have the uid in then it should pass, but because it is not, it fails.

To fix this, you would need to provide some further information on how your db is setup and what you are querying. Ie, you are finding *all* emails which match a criteria, or something else.